# Is there any trouble in using AngularJS 1.* + Dojo Toolkits's Dijit components?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dojo, amd

I have a personal application with factories, directives and filters already done in Angular 1.*, I have some modules, and I want to re-purpose this app.

I want to make a layout based on Dijit Components and it's theme, and use some Dojo core features the same way I could use jQuery.

My doubts:

- Is there any tip in using Dojo Toolkit's features with AngularJS?
- Can I code Dijit's components and Dojo inside AngularJS controllers?
- AngularJS Two-Way Data Binding works with Dijit components?

PS: Dojo uses AMD-based (Asynchronous Module Definition) module architecture.

Comment: Of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545881/is-it-possible-to-combine-dojo-with-other-js-frameworks

Comment: Thanks @GibboK! I appreciate that